# Why is the Event not firing?

Tags: android, events, cordova, resume

I am developing a cross platfom application using cordova. It is planning to support both iOS and Android. The initial page if the application is a login.html which loads for login to the application. From the login.html it will invoke login web service and authenticate the user.
We are opening the login.html from OnCreate method of the CordovaActivity. Using below code.

```
super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
```

Our issue is, when the user is on the login page and he entered the username and password, and then he tap on the home button of the device, then the app will go to background. But when we take back the page from background, only the password should be erased from the password field and username should remain in the login.html.

We tried that with the resume event of cordova. But cordova resume event is not firing.

```
document.addEventListener("resume", OnResume, false);


// Handle the resume event
//
function OnResume() {
    setTimeout(function() {
    alert("OnResume");
    }, 0);
};
```

Hope I have explained my issue properly.

Any help shall be much appreciated. We are struck with this for the last few days. We are using Cordova 3.4.0

Comment: according to the code above you have a typo in `document.addEventListener("resume", OnResume, false);` should be `onResume` not `OnResume`

Comment: Sorry that was only a typo in my question. It was not there in my Code. I corrected that. I have seen similar questions in the forum. But I couldn't find any answer. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you waiting for the document to finish loading before setting the listener?

Comment: You must add event resume when deviceready is fired.